# C++ running out of memory trying to draw large image with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I have created a simple 2D image viewer in C++ using MFC and OpenGL. This image viewer allows a user to open an image, zoom in/out, pan around, and view the image in its different color layers (cyan, yellow, magenta, black). The program works wonderfully for reasonably sized images. However I am doing some stress testing on some very large images and I am easily running out of memory. One such image that I have is 16,700x15,700. My program will run out of memory before it can even draw anything because I am dynamically creating an `UCHAR[]` with a size of `height x width x 4`. I multiply it by 4 because there is one byte for each RGBA value when I feed this array to `glTexImage2D(GLTEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GLUNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*)myArray)`

I've done some searching and have read a few things about splitting my image up into tiles, instead of one large texture on a single quad. Is this something that I should be doing? How will this help me with my memory? Or is there something better that I should be doing?

Comment: Are you really displaying 16k x 16k pixels. Or is this large image just something to pan over with a much smaller window. In the latter case indeed I think tiling would be a good idea, combined with only rendering what's actually visible. And if you zoom out, undersampling (taking every Nth pixel. At least it's what I would try first...

Comment: I think there are 2 basic design choices: Users are required to have machine RAM in relation to the image size they want to work on (industrial strength graphic designers may just go and buy their 128gb RAM if they need it for super large advertisement images or whatever) - you just implement some exception handling to tell the user in a polite way, that his pc specs are not suitable for the image size. The hard way: support partial loading of images from disk and even tiled compression in order to create a mini of the large picture in case of zooming and so on. I'd go with the first choice.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge Yes, ideally I would love to show the entire image if possible. I thought about under sampling, but if/when the user zooms in, won't I have to iterate over the data again to get a new sample?

Comment: @grek40 I am very tempted to go with that first choice you suggested.... do you know of a way in C++ to check a user's RAM size?

Comment: @erics: Yes, undersampling would require you to resample again, so going over your data again, but picking never more than the samples you need, rather than touching all of your data. Still indeed it may be slow.

Comment: thank you @JacquesdeHooge for your suggestions. I'll have to think about what will be best for my situation :)

Comment: @erics You shouldn't check the ram size, just handle cases where allocation fails (out of memory) and have an exception safe cleanup logic (no dangling pointers, release on destructor) and catch at an apropriate place in order to release all resources that are related to the image which failed loading. Only after some cleanup is done you should inform the user, otherwise you might try to build a dialog on zero heap memory.

Comment: alrighty! Thanks a lot @grek40 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your allocation is of size 16.7k * 15.7k * 4 which is ~1GB in size. The rest of the answer depends on whether you are compiling to 32 bit or 64 bit executable and whether you are making use of Physical Address Extensions (PAE). If you are unfamiliar with PAE, chances are you aren't using it, by the way.

Assuming 32 Bit

If you have a 32 bit executable, you can address 3GB of that memory so one third of your memory is being used up in a single allocation. Now, to add to the problem, when you allocate a chunk of memory, that memory must be available as a single continuous range of free memory. You might easily have more than 1GB of memory free but in chunks smaller than 1GB, which is why people suggest you split your texture up into tiles. Splitting it into 32 x 32 smaller tiles means you are allocating 1024 allocations of 1MB for example (this is probably unnecessarily fine-grained).
*Note: citation required but some modes of linux allow only 2GB..*

Assuming 64 Bit

It seems unlikely that you are building a 64 bit executable, but if you were then the logically addressable memory is much higher. Typical numbers will be 2^42 or 2^ 48 (4096 GB and 256 TB, respectively). This means that large allocations shouldn't fail under anything other than artificial stress tests and you will kill your swapfile before you exhaust the logical memory.

**If your constraints / hardware allow, I'd suggest building to 64bit instead of 32bit. Otherwise, see below**

Tiling vs. Subsampling

Tiling and subsampling are not mutually exclusive, up front. You may only need to make one change to solve your problem but you might choose to implement a more complex solution.

Tiling is a good idea if you are in 32 bit address space. It complicates the code but removes the single 1GB contiguous block problem that you seem to be facing. If you must build a 32 bit executable, I would prefer that over sub-sampling the image.

Sub-sampling the image means that you have an additional (albeit-smaller) block of memory for the subsampled vs. original image. It might have a performance advantage inside openGL but set that against additional memory pressure.

A third way, with additional complications is to stream the image from disk when necessary. If you zoom out to show the whole image, you will be subsampling >100 pixels per screen pixel on a 1920 x 1200 monitor. You might choose to create an image that is significantly subsampled by default, and use that until you are sufficiently zoomed-in that you need a higher-resolution version of a ***subset*** of the image. If you are using SSDs this can give acceptable performance but adds a lot by way of additional complication.

Comment: I decided to go the subsampling route and allow the user to zoom in to a portion of the image and display that portion in full resolution. Your answer was very informative and well thought out. I will mark it as correct. Thank you for the help.